# Can I shrink this code with an array or loop?

Tags: javascript

Forgive me, I hope this question isn't too obvious, I'm a javascript noob.

I have javascript code that takes numbers from an xml sheet and displays them in td elements on an html page. It works but I think it could be condensed into an array or a loop to be more efficient.

Is there a better way to write this code?

```
window.onload=function displayPrices()
{
twentyFourK=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("twentyFourK")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.getElementById("twentyFourK").innerHTML=toCurrency(twentyFourK);

oneOzGold=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("oneOzGold")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.getElementById("oneOzGold").innerHTML=toCurrency(oneOzGold);

fiveOzGold=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("fiveOzGold")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.getElementById("fiveOzGold").innerHTML=toCurrency(fiveOzGold);

tenOzGold=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("tenOzGold")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.getElementById("tenOzGold").innerHTML=toCurrency(tenOzGold);

oneKiloGold=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("oneKiloGold")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.getElementById("oneKiloGold").innerHTML=toCurrency(oneKiloGold);

//etc.
}
```

Comment: what's `i`? And __use `var`__ when declaring local variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a function could make things much easier for you:

```
window.onload = function() {
    function loadCurrency(name) {
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = toCurrency(x[i].getElementsByTagName(name)[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
    }

    loadCurrency('twentyFourK');
    loadCurrency('oneOzGold');
    loadCurrency('fiveOzGold');
    loadCurrency('tenOzGold');
    loadCurrency('oneKiloGold');
};
```

---

Also, if you have many items to load:

```
window.onload = function() {
    function loadCurrency(name) {
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = toCurrency(x[i].getElementsByTagName(name)[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
    }

    var items = ['twentyFourK', 'oneOzGold', 'fiveOzGold', 'tenOzGold', 'oneKiloGold'];
    items.forEach(loadCurrency);
};
```

That requires `Array.forEach`, which is only available in ECMAScript 5, so here's a fallback:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(action, thisArg) {
    for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(i in this) {
            action.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would place the currency setting into its own method. This will be cleaner visually and will also allow for implementation changes in the future:

```
window.onload = function displayPrices() {

    SetCurrency("twentyFourK");
    SetCurrency("oneOzGold");

    //etc.
}
function SetCurrency(name) {
    var elements = x[i].getElementsByTagName(name);
    if ((elements != null) && (elements.length != 0)) {
        elements[0].innerHTML = toCurrency(elements[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Is there supposed to be a getElementById(name) somewhere? 

In my xml the elements I'm pulling out are 2 layers deep, would that affect how you write this? It goes `<preciousMetals><goldBars><oneOzGold>` and the function is preceded by `x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("preciousMetals");`

Answer (score 0):

You  could create a function with a list of element in parameter, and you just have to create a loop going through your list of elements (twentyFourK, oneKiloGold and so on)